# Angular6 change site log depending on build configuration

Tags: html, npm, angular6

I have 2 environment setup in my angular 6 web app.

Here I need to change the site logo depending on the environment.

The logo is returned from api. Depending on env how to run the api. And how to use this in components.

I implemented the static logo integration with env config by

### environment.dev

```
     production: true,
  logourl: 'assets/images/logo.png',
```

### environment.test

```
     production: true,
  logourl: 'assets/images/logo1.png',
```

Now the logo url is returned from api as

```
Dev: http://url.com/getlog?cliid=1
test: http://url.com/getlog?cliid=2
```

Where to run this api. If so how to configure this api response to env file.

Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get reference to that environment variable in typescript and use binding to update logo source in HTML.

Typescript:

```
import { environment } from './../../../environments/environment.dev';

logoUrl: string;

constructor{
    this.logoUrl= environment.logourl;
}
```

You can now bind logo url to HTML image like so:

`<img [src]="logourl" />`

Depending on your project setup, when you run Angular in prod, it should replace the import with the corresponding environment file.

When you generate a new project, Angular gives you `environment.ts` for development and `environment.prod.ts` for production.

You'd by default import `environment` in all your components and when you build project for production, Angular swaps the references to production.